# Which Turkish town has the best climate all year round?

Tags: turkey, weather-and-climate

I know Antalya has the best climate all year round. However, it is a crowded beach city. I am looking for a foresty/mountainous small town in Turkey that is sparsely populated.

To me, a good climate means 21-25 degrees Celsius in the summer and 10-15 in the winter. I also need dry air i.e. least amount of humidity. I also need access to healthcare as I have asthma.

Can anyone recommend such a town for a long-term stay of five years?

Comment: Unless you can express what a good climate is, we can not answer this question. I like the climate I live, mild, never cold, never hot. A friend loves the climate he lives, hot in summer, cold in winter. Both will tell you 'my climate is the best.'

Comment: Recommend for what? A short break, long stay holiday, a place to live? Any other considerations, such as accessibility, amenities?

Comment: @user366312, do you have any requirements for humidity, wind (would you object to no wind for several days, on a regular basis; or to strong winds likewise), etc

Comment: @CSM, I need dry air.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a detailed [climate map of Turkey from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Climate_of_Turkey):

[image]

Of the seven sample cities on the page, [Zonguldak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zonguldak) in the Black Sea region seems the best fit, with temperature ranges almost exactly what you are looking for, but the Black Sea coast as a whole is very wet and it rains 7-18 days per month.

[image]

That said, it looks like you're looking for a [Csb: Mediterranean warm/cool summer climate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6ppen_climate_classification#Csb:_Mediterranean_warm/cool_summer_climates), which per the map above *does* exist in small pockets in Turkey.  **[İnegöl](https://weatherspark.com/y/96029/Average-Weather-in-%C4%B0negol-Turkey-Year-Round)**, south of Bursa, is not too far off what you're looking for, although it's still a bit too cold in the winter (average highs around 5°C).